# Unresolved dependency error when updating

Tags: 7, updating

I Tried updating 2 different sites and both gave error messages saying "Unresolved dependency" missing from different modules.

[image]

[image]

[image: Module Versions]

The pages no longer load on the site saying

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function libraries_load()

Why am I getting these messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating core first solved this for me

Comment: sorry, but how to update core if page /update.php does not allow to update core due to unresolved dependencies with modules?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess...

If you're updating modules on a fairly out-of-date site, some of the new versions may now depend on other modules, whereas they didn't when you originally installed them. Either that, or the files have just become missing somehow.

Either way, it looks like you need to download

- [Libraries](https://drupal.org/project/libraries)
- [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token)
- [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views)
- [Phone](https://drupal.org/project/phone)